# Declare Dictionary Of string & array of String in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Have values as

```
Fruit:- Apple,Banana,Mango
Flowers:- Rose,Lotus,Jasmine
Vegetables:-Tomato,Potato,Chilli
```

I want to make `dictionary` as below

In **Objective-C** we can make as:

```
  Nsdictionary dict;
  dict = @{@"Fruit" : @[@"Apple", @"Banana", @"Mango"],
            @"Flowers" : @[@"Rose", @"Lotus",@"Jasmine"],
            @"Vegetables" : @[@"Tomato", @"Potato",@"Chilli"],
          };
```

How to make same `dictionary` in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var dict : Dictionary = ["Fruit" : ["Apple", "Banana", "Mango"],"Flowers" : ["Rose", "Lotus","Jasmine"],"Vegetables" : ["Tomato", "Potato","Chilli"]]
```

You can declare it globally as :

```
var dict : [String : Array<String>] = ["Fruit" : ["Apple", "Banana", "Mango"],"Flowers" : ["Rose", "Lotus","Jasmine"],"Vegetables" : ["Tomato", "Potato","Chilli"]]
```

You can declare an empty `Dictonary` this way:

```
var dict : [String : Array<String>] = Dictionary()
```

Comment: Dictionary <key,value> is not convertible to "Dictionary" error comes

Comment: I have declared it in particular swift class.Where to declare it?

Comment: thank u it works. my mistake now I have declared it in view didload

Comment: you can also create an empty dictionary this way `var dict = [String : [String]]()`